# Google Finance API, how to retrieve identical ticker symbols in python on two exchanges

Tags: equities, python, google

Stock data retrieval form Google. Example: I want to retrieve the stock data for Infosys. Infosys has two listings with the same ticker symbol but on a different exchange and in different currencies (ADR and ADS).

```
exchange: NYSE
ticker: INFY
google company id: 663089
ccy: USD
exchange timezone: America/New_York

exchange: EPA
ticker: INFY
google company id: 853018699393258
ccy: EUR
exchange timezone: Europe/Paris
```

Using the google finance API in python it returns me the values for the NYSE listing. Is there a way to call the information for the other ticker in Europe as well?

```
df = web.DataReader(name='INFY', data_source='google', start='20170308', end='20170308')
print(df)

      Open   High    Low  Close   Volume
Date                                          
2017-03-08    15  15.09  14.93  14.97  5673225
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, you can include the exchange code along with the symbol. For example, for INFY on NYSE, you can do:

`web.DataReader('NYSE:INFY', 'google')`

However, it appears that Google Finance does not allow you to export EPA data, so `EPA:INFY` wouldn't work and you'll need to find a different data provider.

Answer (score 1):

interestingly enough, using yahoo with the right ticker symbol does give you the European prices

web.DataReader('INFY.PA', 'yahoo')